# Strange activity detected in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I developed a chrome extension to keep track of websites visited by the user.
I am using following chrome event listeners,

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function tabUpdated(tabId, changeInfo,tab) 
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function tabActivated(tabId) 
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function tabClosed(tabId)
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function windowClosed(windowId)
chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(function (idleState)
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function windowChanged(windowId)
```

It is almost working as expected, sending logs regarding when a tab was open or closed.
But sometimes randomly, i get stats regarding opening of pages that i never opened, and these are from these domains

```
accounts.google.com
facebook.com/login.php
nytimes.com
localhost:7200
```

Even if i dont open these pages i get stats for their activity, and the dates of the activities are in future (2017). I have debugged a lot, added logs in console, but console does not show such activity. I am not sure if it is due to interference of some other extension or some other reason. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The nytimes one is probably from a news extension; accounts.google.com is used for auto-login; same with facebook probably; and localhost:7200 I don't know. That's my guess.

Comment: `sending logs` - where? how? `the dates of the activities are in future` - your extension has a bug, not that you've shown any code, so that's a guess too

Comment: While this is interesting, without enough code and information (e.g. describing user interaction; showing logs, etc.) for us to duplicate the issue, we basically have to **guess** at what the causes might be. Please [edit] the question to provide both a [mcve] and enough information to duplicate the issue. As has been hinted at by others, please be sure you are testing in a new "person" that does not have any non-stock extensions installed. If you do [edit] the question to provide enough to duplicate the problem, please ping me by posting a comment with `@Makyen` in it.